# Generic "get in touch" icon

Tags: icons, email, actions, contact-us, telephone

I usually use the phone call icons, or email, sms, and so on.

But in my case we found the need for a generic "get in touch" icon, which will lead to either email, or phonecall, or sms, depending on what is available.

Is there an icon for such a feature? Right now I'm looking at hybrid icons with a phone over an envelope for example, but while that would do the trick, I'm curious if there is anything more to find out here.

Is there an icon that exists for such an action?

Comment: Hi Gil Sand, I invite you to put this question at [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions) where I think it belongs

Comment: Ooh, that's right. My bad ; it does indeed have nothing to do here :) I'll vote for close.

Comment: Thinking aloud before it gets moved: A stylised person's head? Perhaps with speech bubble?

Comment: that's a pretty cool idea. I like it :)

Comment: I would argue that this DOES belong here as its more than visual communication. Its interface and the implied meaning which is very much a UX problem

Answer (score 1):

A speech bubble, like @TripleHound mentioned, might work. However, don't choose one what looks like an SMS bubble to avoid confusion.

The idea of a person's head might also work, but it would have to symbolize a customer service person (with a headset), to avoid confusing with a "Log In" person head.

Check here for more ideas:
https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=contact%20us